# Number of electrons in an atom referenced by Rutherford

Tags: electrons, atoms

I have been reading the original paper of Rutherford and came across his reference of a paper from J.A. Crowther.

> Crowther concluded that the number of corpuscles in an atom is equal to about three times its atomic weight in terms of hydrogen.

The above quote is verbatim from the abstract:
[Abstract of Rutherford's paper, 1911](https://www.chemteam.info/Chem-History/Rutherford-atom-abstract.html)

Now that would mean for Hydrogen 3 electrons, Neon 60 and so forth, which contradicts our current numbers derived from Moseley's experiments. I cannot see any attempt to refute the number, only the structure. What I am missing here?

Comment: Look at the date ,1911, the progress of experimental and theoretical physics since then has given a consistent validated model of atoms . Why would one have to refute models that are wrong because the data they used at that time was wrong or incomplete?

Comment: @annav Thank you for taking attention to the question. I agree that we have a different view on atoms now, but the paper of Crowther describes an experiment whose results can be reproduced to the present. Could you therefore please name the newer experiments that favoured Moseleys spectral lines over Crowther?
Also, since you are very experienced, could you help out with this other question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/670752/invalid-structure-of-atoms-on-a-classical-scale-and-wrong-assumption-for-the-tim
Thank you

Comment: "the paper of Crowther describes an experiment whose results can be reproduced to the present. " do you have a link?

Comment: [Crowther p 240](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1910.0074) distinctly states he produces his number *assuming positive electricity is uniformly distributed*! (Assumption A!)

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you, I missed this. Do you want to put this as an answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: No, I don't think future readers would appreciate deconstructions of questions... You could withdraw/delete the question.